# Issue while using UIRotationGestureRecognizer to rotate Image?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform, image-rotation

I am trying to implement `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` for `UIImageView`.

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotateGesture = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:rotateGesture];
```

and in the selector method, I have dont this

```
-(void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        selectedImage.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(selectedImage.transform, gesture.rotation);

        [gesture setRotation:0];
    }

}
```

With the above code, image is rotating. But, the problem is, Image center is getting changed. with that, image rotating is looking bit Awkward.

Initial center for Image is `(277,653)`
While rotating, value are getting increased till `(365,659)`  and then again, it is coming back to `(277,653)`.

What could be the reason? How to fix the center? How can I make my image to rotate at center of the `UIImageView` using `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
recognizer.rotation = 0;
```

Here's a tutorial. Hope it helps

[Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more)

Comment: I have done exactly as what he has done. I have run the sample code. Its working fine. But, If I write, then I am facing the problem again. I am using iOS6. The SDK which I am using is also the latest one. Is there any issues with the latest SDK? Can u please try once using the latest SDK? I am getting the same problem

Comment: Found the problem. Its because of the AutoLayout feature in iOS 6. I have deselected it. Now, its working fine. Thanks anyways.